# Ghostscript: producing searchable PDF with 'gxps'

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, xps

I have a searchable XPS file which I convert to PDF like this:

```
gxps -sOutputFile=C:\temp\foo.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
     -dNOPAUSE C:\temp\foo.xps
```

The resulting PDF is not searchable.

- Is there a way for `gxps` to generate searchable PDFs?
- If not, is there an similar app that can convert searchable XPS to searchable PDF on the command line?

**Edit:**

```
gxps version: 9.15
Build date: Mon Sep 22 12:35:05 2014
```

- Sample input XPS file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/01rd7apzjb1kwuo/forSO.xps?dl=0
- Sample output PDF file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pefslcyznns5gim/forSO.pdf?dl=0

Comment: It would be helpful to know which version of GhostScript you are using (gxps versions are synced to GS releases), and also to see an example of such a file. It may or may not be possible to convert an XPS file into a PDF and create a ToUnicode CMa, but at present I doubt gxps does this. If there is no ToUnicode CMap on the input (can't be, in an XPS file) then the PDF won't contain one, searchability then depends totally on heuristics and teh character code mapping. Technically it should be possible to do though, I think.

Comment: Can you provide a (link to a) sample XPS input file to play with?

Comment: There, I added GhostScript version and sample files. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at the PDF and quickly investigated the fonts used by GXPS for the resulting PDF file, using `pdffonts`:

```
 $ pdffonts forSO.pdf

   name                    type         encoding         emb sub uni object ID
   ----------------------- ------------ ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
   RFGWZI+Arial            TrueType     WinAnsi          yes yes yes     11  0
```

Superficially, it looks OK:

1. The only font used is embedded (see `emb` column).
2. The font type is a common one (see `type` column).
3. The font encoding is a standard one (see `encoding` column).
4. The font seems to have a companion `/ToUnicode` map (see `uni` column).

Looking more closely however, the real `/ToUnicode` map which was embedded into the PDF by `gxps` seems to be heavily b0rken. Here is it, extracted as a complete indirect object from the PDF, with uncompressed stream:

```
41 0 obj
<<
  /Length 863
>>
stream
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CMapType 2 def
/CMapName/R41 def
1 begincodespacerange
<00><ff>
endcodespacerange
42 beginbfrange
<04><04><0004>
<05><05><0004>
<06><06><0006>
<07><07><0006>
<08><08><0006>
<09><09><0006>
<0a><0a><000a>
<0b><0b><000a>
<0c><0c><000c>
<0d><0d><000c>
<0e><11><000e>
<12><12><000c>
<13><13><000c>
<14><14><000c>
<15><15><000c>
<16><16><0004>
<17><17><0004>
<18><18><0004>
<19><1a><0019>
<1b><1b><001a>
<1c><1c><001a>
<1d><1d><001a>
<1e><1e><001a>
<1f><1f><001a>
<20><20><0044>
<21><21><001a>
<22><22><001a>
<23><23><001a>
<24><24><0024>
<25><25><000c>
<26><26><001d>
<27><27><0023>
<28><28><0023>
<29><29><0028>
<41><41><0044>
<44><44><0044>
<49><49><0044>
<63><63><0044>
<69><69><0044>
<74><74><0044>
<76><76><0044>
<79><79><0044>
endbfrange
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end end
endstream
endobj
```

As one can see, the `/ToUnicode` table contains 42 keys, but these do map to only 12 different character values:

- Some of these 12 different character values appear multiple times in this table, hence reverse-mapping multiple glyphs to the same character (which in turn does not seem to be correct even for a single one):

  ```
       no. of |   char 
  occurrences |   value
  ------------+-----------
           1  |   <000e>
           1  |   <0019>
           1  |   <001d>
           1  |   <0024>
           1  |   <0028>
           2  |   <000a>
           2  |   <0023>
           4  |   <0006>
           5  |   <0004>
           7  |   <000c>
           8  |   <001a>
           9  |   <0044>
  ```
- For example, character value `06` maps to glyphs with the numbers `06`, `07`, `08` and `09`.

This doesn't look right.

IMHO, this would deserve a bug report into **[Ghostscript's Bugzilla](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/)** (but I'm not sure if the GXPS component is still actively maintained or not).

***Update:*** I found an existing entry into the Ghostscript/GXPS bugzilla database here:

- **[Bug 693945 - Incorrect Unicode Map Generated by gxps/pdfwrite](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693945)**